# Audit only changes to files

Tags: auditd

I'm using Auditd to record any changes to files. Here is rule:

```
# auditctl -l
LIST_RULES: exit,always dir=/var/local/ (0x1e) perm=w key=state-files
```

but if I run:

```
# ausearch -i -k state-files
```

command I got:

```
...
type=PATH msg=audit(04/27/16 12:51:42.793:8700) : item=0 name=/var/local/some/path/file inode=6100653 dev=08:01 mode=file,644 ouid=someuser ogid=admin rdev=00:00 
type=CWD msg=audit(04/27/16 12:51:42.793:8700) :  cwd=/opt/app/bin 
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(04/27/16 12:51:42.793:8700) : arch=x86_64 syscall=open success=yes exit=125 a0=7f9f602ecfa0 a1=241 a2=1b6 a3=7f9f75f69e20 items=1 ppid=13812 pid=13814 auid=unset uid=someuser gid=somegroup euid=xxx suid=ccc fsuid=zzz egid=aaa sgid=bbb fsgid=sss tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=java exe=/opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java key=state-files
...
```

Problem is that ausearch reports opening of files, even if perm is set to writes only. I want to report only changes to files, not reads.